# cloud-sql-proxy for GCP Dataproc fails, nc: connect to localhost port 3306 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, cloud-sql-proxy

I am using Terraform to create a dataproc cluster that uses a GCP cloudsql instance as the hivemetastore, the terrafrm project creates the cluster and all its prerequisites (network, service account, cloudsql instance & user, etc).
[`cloud-sql-proxy.sh`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy) is provided to assist with this however I can't get it to work, when the cluster is created `cloud-sql-proxy.sh` fails with error:

> nc: connect to localhost port 3306 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

I've banged my head against the wall trying to figure out why but can't get to the bottom of it so am hoping someone here can help.

I've hosted the terraform project at https://github.com/jamiekt/democratising-dataproc. Reproducing the problem is very easy, follow these steps:

1. [Install terraform](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/install) if you haven't already
2. Install `gcloud` if you haven't already
3. Create a new GCP project
4. Enable the [Cloud Dataproc API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/dataproc.googleapis.com) for your new project
5. `gcloud auth application-default login #creates a file containing credentials that terraform will use`
6. `git clone git@github.com:jamiekt/democratising-dataproc.git && cd democratising-dataproc`
7. `export GCP_PROJECT=name-of-project-you-just-created`
8. `make init`
9. `make apply`

That should successfully spin up a network, subnetwork, cloudsql instance, a couple of storage buckets (one of them containing cloud-sql-proxy.sh), a service account, a firewall then fail when attempting to create the dataproc cluster.

if anyone could take a look and tell me why this is failing I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Did you try to follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-apache-hive-on-cloud-dataproc) article on how to configure Hive Metastore to use Cloud SQL on Dataproc?

Comment: thank you @IgorDvorzhak, your responses helped. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of problems here that have now been solved:

- [service_account_scopes needed specifying and `hive:hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` property needed setting](https://github.com/jamiekt/democratising-dataproc/commit/14dd85c849fb140a550fa875630e171390575b23)
- [Terraform removes the default root user from MySQL so it has to be recreated. I was missing (amongst other things) the host attribute (`host = '%'`)](https://github.com/jamiekt/democratising-dataproc/commit/f6729e6b14496a9b0c5f77d24caeaabaa0228d9f)
- various other things

The [state of the repo at the time of posting this message](https://github.com/jamiekt/democratising-dataproc/tree/e4931a9ce4cfb6f27713b127a7d2e82bfb5d5477) will work as intended (i.e. create, using Terraform, a dataproc cluster that uses a shared hive metastore).

Thank you @igor-dvorzhak for your responses, your link to the article on configuring Hive Metastore to use Cloud SQL put me on the right track..

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not using the latest version of [cloud-sql-proxy.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh) script in the [cloud-sql-proxy.sh.tmpl](https://github.com/jamiekt/democratising-dataproc/blob/master/scripts/cloud-sql-proxy.sh.tmpl) template ([diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/3ZsuCWRf)).

You may want to try to update your template with latest script version from Dataproc [Cloud SQL I/O and Hive Metastore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/cloud-sql-proxy) initialization action.